# numpy : float indices to interpolate

Tags: python, numpy

What I would like to do is as follows :

I have a vector A which is initially zeros

```
[0,0,0]
```

I am given a float index

```
0.5
```

What I mean by interpolating with float index is a function that will have such output

```
[0.5,0.5,0]
```

A few more examples

```
1 -> [0,1,0]
2 -> [0,0,1]
1.5 -> [0,0.5,0.5]
1.9 -> [0,0.1,0.9]
```

How is this called and what function in numpy does the behavior I described above?

Comment: The `np.interp` function might be what you need.

Comment: I don't understand the logic. Please explain much more rigorously

Answer (score 2):

The function you describe could be thought of as interpolating between the rows (or columns) of a suitably-sized identity matrix: an input of `0` gives the
first basis vector `[1, 0, 0]`, an input of `1` gives `[0, 1, 0]`, and so on, and non-integer inputs interpolate between the two nearest vectors.

NumPy's [`interp`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) function doesn't support interpolation between vectors, but SciPy's [`interp1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html) does, and gives you exactly what you need. Here's a demonstration:

```
>>> from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
>>> import numpy as np
>>> interpolator = interp1d(np.arange(3), np.identity(3))
>>> interpolator(0.5)
array([0.5, 0.5, 0. ])
>>> interpolator(1)
array([0., 1., 0.])
>>> interpolator(2)
array([0., 0., 1.])
>>> interpolator(1.5)
array([0. , 0.5, 0.5])
>>> interpolator(1.9)
array([0. , 0.1, 0.9])
```

You don't say what behaviour you'd want for *extrapolation*. That is, for inputs smaller than `0.0` or greater than `2.0`. But SciPy offers you various options here, too. By default, it will raise an exception:

```
>>> interpolator(-0.2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/polyint.py", line 78, in __call__
    y = self._evaluate(x)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py", line 677, in _evaluate
    below_bounds, above_bounds = self._check_bounds(x_new)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py", line 706, in _check_bounds
    raise ValueError("A value in x_new is below the interpolation "
ValueError: A value in x_new is below the interpolation range.
```

But you can also extrapolate, or provide a fill value. Here's an extrapolation example:

```
>>> interpolator = interp1d(np.arange(3), np.identity(3), fill_value="extrapolate")
>>> interpolator(-0.2)
array([ 1.2, -0.2,  0. ])
```

Answer (score 1):

This function makes no mathematical sense to me, so I doubt numpy has it.

Here is a python solution

```
def to_strange_list(n):
    assert 0<=n<=2
    if n == 2:
        print([0.0, 0.0, 1.0])
        return
    number_dec = n % 1
    if 0<=n<1:
        n = number_dec
        far_from_next = 1 - n
        far_from_prev = n
        a = [far_from_next, far_from_prev, 0]
    else:
        n = number_dec + 1
        far_from_next = 2 - n
        far_from_prev = n - 1
        a = [0, far_from_next, far_from_prev]

    print(a)

to_strange_list(0.9)
to_strange_list(1.9)
to_strange_list(1.0)
to_strange_list(2.0)
```

out:

```
[0.09999999999999998, 0.9, 0]
[0, 0.10000000000000009, 0.8999999999999999]
[0, 1.0, 0.0]
[0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
```